# Some relative paths on macOS 10.15 Catalina beta (19A471t) do not work

Tags: bash, npm, zsh, macos-catalina

There's an odd behaviour when using relative paths. For example:

```
$ cd /Users
$ ls -l ../bin
ls: ../bin: No such file or directory

$ ls -l /bin
-r-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   623344 31 May 08:33 bash
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    36768 31 May 08:33 cat
...
```

But the following works fine:

```
$ cd /dev
$ ls -l ../bin
-r-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   623344 31 May 08:33 bash
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    36768 31 May 08:33 cat
...
```

Some other directories do not return the **No such file or directory** message, but they act as if there was nothing there. For example:

```
$ cd /Users
$ ls -l ../dev
$
```

returns nothing, and back to the prompt. The following, however, works fine:

```
$ cd /bin
$ ls -l ../dev
crw-------  1 root    wheel      19,   1 11 Jun 16:54 afsc_type5
crw-------  1 root    wheel      10,   0 11 Jun 16:54 auditpipe
crw-r--r--  1 root    wheel       9,   3 11 Jun 16:54 auditsessions
...
```

I could not find anything on the release notes. The WWDC2019 session 710 (**What's New in Apple File Systems**) also does not mention anything.

I think it might be related to the new separation of directories into a read-only and a read-write volumes. But still, it should work.

I found this to be specially problematic when using `npm link`, which links to `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/...` but expressed as a relative path from the destination package. After linking I have to manually change the link from relative to absolute. An ugly hack that may have some unforeseen consequences.

Anybody any clues?

Comment: `pwd`? Also doesn't this actually belong to Unix/Linux StackExchange

Comment: what about pwd. It just shows the current working directory. Nothing wrong with that. The problem is that some relative paths are not properly resolved.

Comment: I don't thing this belongs to Unix/Linux StackExchange, it is a specific macOS-catalina problem, most likely a bug, as it is still in beta phase. But the reason I am posting it here, is because it affects npm link, which seems to be now broken. As a hack I am linking my modules manually, but I do not know what side effects that might have.

Comment: so does `pwd` print `/Users/` in `/Users/`'

Comment: yes. pwd works fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved with in Catalina beta 4.